# Remove duplicates based on common where condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Select * from Table_name  i am getting below result.

```
S.no    Emp_id  Date       Description  Amount    Splitup amount 
2667737 12345   8/12/2019   Icecream    50          30 
2667738 12345   8/12/2019   Icecream    50          20
2667739 12346   8/12/2019   Chocolate   50          20
```

But i need the result

```
S.no    Emp_id  Date      Description   Amount  Splitup amount
2667737 12345   8/12/2019 Icecream        50    30
2667738 12345             Icecream              20
2667739 12346   8/12/2019 Chocolate 50          20
```

i need only the first as amount .For same s.no and same emp_id was to have only one date and amount, remaining rows i want to make it empty.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, what RDBMS are you *really* using? Please retag the one you are using. What have *you* tried to sovle the problem yourself, and why didn't it work?  What is the logic in terms of not displayed values in the second row? This seems like it might be something for your display layer.

Comment: You need to tell us the **logic or rules that explain why** the second row should be partially cleared. I feel that it has to do with the `Amount` of 50 vs the `Splitup amount` values of 30 and 20, but you forgot to tell us these important details.

Comment: But with the amount vs split up amount..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using `lag()` windows analytic function :

```
select [S.no], [Emp_id],
       case when lag([Date],1,null) over 
           (partition by [Date] order by [S.no]) = [Date] then
             null
       else
             [Date]
       end as [Date], [Description],
       case when lag([Amount],1,null) over 
           (partition by [Amount] order by [S.no]) = [Amount] then
             null
       else
             [Amount]
       end as [Amount], [Splitup amount]
  from tab;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4a9ff4132e54e014d7c14c3a4b8380dd)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a Lot it worked for me..

Comment: than you, too @VinothNarayan

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional logic with `row_number()`:

```
select s.s_no, s.emp_id, 
       (case when row_number() over (partition by emp_id, description order by s_no) = 1
             then date
        end) as date,
       description,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by emp_id, description order by s_no) = 1
             then amount
        end) as amount,
       splitup
from t
order by emp_id, s_no;
```

Note the outer `order by` and how it matches the conditions in the window clause.  SQL result sets are unordered unless there is an explicit `order by`.  If you want the "first" row to have the values, then you need to be sure that the result set is in the right order.

Comment: It's not working @gordon

Comment: @VinothNarayan . . . "not working" conveys basically no information.  You need to explain what happens.